# How to set Single Selection in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter) for my recyclerview. It has a option for Multiselect Recyclerview.

But I need to select only one Item in my RV. If the second Item is selected then the first Item has to be unselected automatically. How can I achieve this ? You can see the Full code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/drmkraja/f14f38f1fc8a88047123c3907ba0c724)

**Activity.java**

```
List<Category> localApiResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cause);

 mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);

        mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter();
        mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerRenderer(createStargazerRenderer(R.layout.item_cat_prefs));
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);

       mViewModel.getCauseDetails().observe(this, apiResponse -> {
        if (apiResponse != null) {
            localApiResponse = apiResponse;
            progressBar.hide();
            mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(localApiResponse);
            mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

private ViewRenderer createStargazerRenderer(final int layout) {
        return new StargazerViewRenderer(layout, new Listener(), 1);
    }

    private class Listener implements StargazerViewRenderer.Listener {

        @Override
        public void onStargazerItemClicked(@NonNull final Category model, final boolean isChecked) {
            mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            this.onStargazerClicked(model, isChecked);
        }

        public void onStargazerClicked(@NonNull final Category model, final boolean isChecked) {
```

int index = localApiResponse.indexOf(model.getID());
Log.e("onStargazerClicked: ", String.valueOf(index));

```
            if (isChecked) {
        Category mModel = model;
        mModel.setChecked(isChecked);
        localApiResponse.set(index+1, mModel);
                mSelectedUsers.add(model.getID());
                model.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                mSelectedUsers.remove(model.getID());
                model.setChecked(false);
            }
        mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(localApiResponse);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

**StargazerViewRenderer.java**

```
public class StargazerViewRenderer extends ViewRenderer<Category, ViewFinder> {

    private int mSelectedItem = -1;
public StargazerViewRenderer(final int layoutID, @NonNull final Listener listener, int mode) {
    super(layoutID, Category.class, (model, finder, payloads) -> finder
            .setVisibility(R.id.check, model.getChecked() ? VISIBLE : GONE)
            .find(R.id.avatar, (ViewProvider<AvatarView>) urlImageView -> {
                urlImageView.setUrl(model.getImageUrl());

            })
            .setText(R.id.title, model.getName())
            .setOnClickListener(() -> {
                Log.e("VR > ", "SELECTED");
                final boolean willChecked = finder.find(R.id.check).getVisibility() == GONE;
                finder.find(R.id.check).setVisibility(willChecked ? VISIBLE : GONE);
                listener.onStargazerItemClicked(model, willChecked);
                model.setChecked(true);
            })
            .setOnClickListener(R.id.check, () -> {
                Log.e("VR > ", "DE > SELECTED");
                final boolean willChecked = finder.find(R.id.check).getVisibility() == GONE;
                finder.find(R.id.check).setVisibility(willChecked ? VISIBLE : GONE);
                listener.onStargazerItemClicked(model, willChecked);
                model.setChecked(false);
            }));
}

@Nullable
@Override
public ViewState createViewState() {
    return new StargazerViewState();
}

@Override
public int createViewStateID(@NonNull final Category model) {
    return Integer.parseInt(model.getID());
}

public interface Listener {
    void onStargazerItemClicked(@NonNull Category model, final boolean isChecked);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your `apiResponse` to local field, ex: `localApiResponse = apiResponse`
2. When `onStargazerClicked` is called, find your model in the local `apiResponse` and switch the `checked` flag
3. Call `setItems(localApiResponse)` and `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Also pay attention at the `StargazerViewState`, looks like it is unused

Comment: Where should I remove the previous selected item & select the current Item ?

Comment: in place where you will save `localApiResponce` field